# Centered finite-difference in Scilab

Tags: scilab

Problem: Use the following data to find the velocity and acceleration
at t = 10 seconds:

```
  Time, t, s     0   2    4    6    8    10  12   14    16

 Position, x, m  0  0.7  1.8  3.4  5.1  6.3  7.3  8.0  8.4
```

I resolved the centered finite-difference

[image]

How can I apply this in Scilab?

Answer (score 0):

This calculates velocity from the given arrays x and t, using central differences:

```
v = (x(3:$) - x(1:$-2)) ./ (t(3:$) - t(1:$-2))
```

To see what this does, focus on the first index in each range:

```
(x(3) - x(1)) ./ (t(3) - t(1))
```

Clearly, this is the velocity at the 2nd moment of time. The formula performs this calculation for all times when it's possible to do; the centered difference formula does not apply at the first and last moment. One may want to introduce truncated time range to reflect this:

```
tr = t(2:$-1)
```

Similarly for acceleration:

```
a = (x(3:$) - 2*x(2:$-1) + x(1:$-2)) ./ (t(3:$) - t(1:$-2)).^2
```

This can now be plotted with `plot(tr,v)` or `plot(tr,a)`. And to look up their values when time is 10, use

```
v(tr==10)
```

and

```
a(tr==10)
```